# How do I prevent HTML output from PHP to show up in the browser?

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm quite new to PHP, so I suspect a stupid mistake. I've looked around for someone with a similar problem, but couldn't find any.

So I have a PHP file that's supposed to output some HTML from a template (via [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)). Instead of seeing the HTML rendered in Chrome, I see the HTML text itself. Here's the PHP code I'm using:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

ob_start();
include_once '../api/get_article.php';
$a_json = ob_get_clean();
$data = json_decode($a_json, true);

require('./libs/Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = './templates/';
$smarty->compile_dir = './templates_c';

$smarty->assign("title_text",$data['title']);

$smarty->display('content.tpl');

?>
```

I thought that it was a problem with encoding, but I made sure that *everything* uses UTF-8 (that is, MYSQL, the HTTP header, and the template file). What else could it be?

Comment: Can you dump the headers you're getting back from the script? Maybe smarty is also setting headers somewhere that are conflicting

Comment: Do you see just the actual HTML tags, or is it the PHP code that is showing, ie. the HTML is enclosed in PHP tags. Stupid question, but is the file named *.php, and is php running on the server ?

Comment: @adeneo The PHP code is running. What I see in the browser is the contents of the template file (content.tpl).

Comment: View Source in your browser. Check if it is outputting the HTML as intended or if you're maybe HTML-escpaing your HTML by accident.

Comment: Indeed, first check the source of the browser page to see if php is interpreting the script at all, otherwise you can download LiveHTTPHeaders for firefox (addon) and see the headers you get back from the server.

Comment: Can you please check Chrome if the header you set in your code is present in the HTTP response? Additionally can you check the source of the webpage to exclude any possibility of the output just being escaped at some point by smarty?

Comment: @deceze The 'View Source' is showing exactly what the browser shows.

Comment: And the browser is showing valid HTML code ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes. I can post the code if you want to verify, it's very short.

Comment: is content.tpl exactly the same as the browser content? in that case smarty just isnt parsing the template but spitting it out directly

Comment: @Garuda Well, not _exactly_. It has the title in it that's all.

Comment: Hassan, please open the Chrome developer tools window, go to Network, start capture with the round button the reload your page. Now click the "GET" text next to the entry for your HTML (It should be the topmost result), browse to "Headers" and check the Content-Type header

Comment: You have a DOCTYPE, and the document is valid ?

Comment: @Codemonkey Huh... It's showing application/json...

Comment: @Codemonkey Not sure how that happened...

Comment: Move your header statement to just before the smarty->display

Comment: @adeneo Why don't you guys answer, so I can up-vote / accept?

Comment: See, Codemonkey answered it for you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty or the `get_article.php` script must be setting the content type header for you at some point. Try moving the line

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

All the way down to right above the `display` function to make sure it overrides any changes made earlier